# Android LocationClient always fails to connect

Tags: java, android, gps

I am trying to implement LocationClient for a personal project, unfortunately, when calling LocationClient's connect() method, it always fails.
I tried on the emulator, then on an android device.
Concerning the android device, i tried only with wifi, only with data, with wifi and GPS and then with data and GPS. Still fails...

Here is my class :

package com.quentin_cheval.quickpint;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;


public class SearchActivity extends Activity implements
        GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener
{

    LocationClient mLocationClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

        TextView goTV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.buttonGo);
        goTV.setClickable(true);

        goTV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                mLocationClient = new LocationClient(SearchActivity.this, SearchActivity.this, SearchActivity.this);
                mLocationClient.connect();
               // Intent intent = new Intent(SearchActivity.this, SearchResultActivity.class);
               // startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle)
    {
        Log.i("QUICKPINT", "CONNECTED");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult)
    {
        Log.i("QUICKPINT", "Fail");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected()
    {
        Log.i("QUICKPINT", "DISCONNECTED");
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot for you help!

Comment: Is your device GPS on?

Comment: Hi. Yes it is. As i said, I tried only with wifi, only with data, with wifi and GPS and then with data and GPS. Still fails...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the ConnectionResult connectionResult to see if you can find more info regarding reason for failure. also check logcat

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your answer. Here is Connection result content :

ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_MISSING, resolution=null}

It seems that google play service is missing on the device :/
(http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult.html)